# git push permission denied deploying on Clever Cloud

Tags: git, github, playframework

I want to deploy a Play application on Cever Cloud but I'm having some issues.

On GitHub I have this repository: myPlayApp.

On Clever Cloud I've added a new application and I've recived a deployement URL.

Now with Git Shell I want to deploy. This is what I get:

```
C:\dev\myPlayApp [master]> git remote add clever git+ssh://git@push.clever-cloud.com/app_9b269ee5-4759-43bb-a8f6-3d8683b31259.git
C:\dev\myPlayApp [master]> git remote -v 
clever  git+ssh://git@push.clever-cloud.com/app_9b269ee5-4759-43bb-a8f6-3d8683b31259.git (fetch)
clever  git+ssh://git@push.clever-cloud.com/app_9b269ee5-4759-43bb-a8f6-3d8683b31259.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/zmoka/myPlayApp.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/zmoka/myPlayApp.git (push)
C:\dev\myPlayApp [master]> git push clever master
Warning: Permanently added 'push.clever-cloud.com,62.210.121.148' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Password:
Password:
Password:
Received disconnect from 62.210.121.148: 2: Too many authentication failures for git
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have already regenerated and tested my ssh key and all works fine:

```
C:\dev\myPlayApp [master]> ssh -T git@github.com
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.129' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Hi zmoka! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Anyone kows how to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you actually added your ssh key to clever cloud? The fact that you can auth to *github* doesn't mean you can auth to other places. http://doc.clever-cloud.com/admin-console/ssh-keys/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have added a key to Clever Cloud but not the right one!!! With the right one all works fine :)